# How does 2d interpolation over 1d works using interp2 in matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Need some help understanding the interp2.Here is example

```
[x y] = meshgrid([1:4],[1:4]);
l = [ 5 6 7 8;9 10 11 12;13 14 15 16; 17 18 19 20];
m = [ 1 2 3 4];
n = [2 3 4 5];
c = interp2(x,y,l,m,n);
```

How does 2d x y matrix getting interpolated over 1D m and n matrix. I will appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you are interpolating at the points (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5). First three are elements of your input, they are basically copied. The last one is not within your input range so it's NAN

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it but why do we want to provide x and y gridpoints for interpolation and how does it helps for interpolation?. Thank you

Comment: @user3499820 - The grid points are defined as the **key** points in your data.  If you want to interpolate values, the key points are used as the base information to get your interpolated values.  The best example would be having a set of key points where the `x` and `y` directions range from `[1,5]`.  Therefore, if you wanted to interpolate at a point at... say... `(1.2,1.2)`, it would use the key points as the base information... so you would need `x` and `y` values between `1` and `2` and interpolate to produce what you desire.